# Interesting Encoding

Tags: character-encoding

I have an interesting promblem with social network http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/.
When I use advanced searching my cyrillic symbols are encoded in no understantable symbols for me.
For Example:
Иван Иванов Encode %25D0%25B8%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2+%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B2%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a **double** URL-encoded string.  The `%25` sequences represent the percent sign.  Decoding once gives `%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2`.

Decoding again gives the UTF-8 string `иванов иванов`.

Answer (score 0):

That's URL- or percent- encoding. The percent starts it. Then its the 4 hex-digits for the char. The `+` is the space.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears to be twice URL encoded. If we unwrap it once, we get

> %D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2 %D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2

and again, we get

> иванов иванов

This appears to be UTF-8 with the bytes encoded separately.